# Why am I getting a syntax error in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM Members
WHERE ID IN 
    (SELECT Member ID 
     FROM Team Member 
     WHERE Team ID IN 
          (SELECT ID 
            FROM Teams 
            WHERE Year = 2012 AND Country = 'Phillipines'))
```

When I input this query into phpmyadmin, I get error #1064 saying I do not have the correct syntax. How can resolve this?

Comment: I suppose it's the "space" between "Member" and "ID" respectively "Team" and "ID" in `SELECT Member ID FROM Team Member WHERE Team ID [...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate error appears to be `WHERE Team ID IN ...` which should actually be `WHERE TeamID IN ...`.  There are also other similar errors.  But, we can try rewriting your query using joins, so that it is more readable and maintainable:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Name
FROM Members m
INNER JOIN TeamMember tm
    ON m.ID = tm.MemberID
INNER JOIN Teams t
    ON tm.TeamID = t.ID
WHERE
    t.Year = 2012 AND t.Country = 'Phillipines';
```

In general, identifiers in SQL have to be a single word without any whitespace.  If `Team ID` is actually a column name, then you would have to refer to it in MySQL using backticks.  But, you should avoid doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your table `Team Member` and its columns `Member ID` and `Team ID` maybe mispelled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using wrong variable name (Member ID) it should not have space in between Member and Id. in the same way (Team Member), (Team ID).
Please make sure you use the right name for column name and table name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using join

```
    SELECT a.ID, a.Name
    FROM Members a inner join Team b on a.ID=b.MemberID
    inner join Teams c on b.TeamID=c.ID
    where c.Year = 2012 AND c.Country = 'Phillipines'
```